# Filters in sidebar menu not showing in R shiny

Tags: r, filter, shiny

I am trying to create filters in the sidebar menu.The code is below

```
data:
col1
a
b
c
```

ui.R

```
dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title = "Dashboard",titleWidth = 2000,disable = F),
  dashboardSidebar(disable = T,
                   
                   sidebarMenu(
                     
                     menuItem(
                              # Input directly under menuItem
                              selectInput("input1", "Select input",
                                          choices = c(unique(data$col1))
                                          )
                     ) 
                              )
  ),
  dashboardBody()
)
```

server.R

```
shinyServer(function(input, output,session){
  print('shiny')
  
  do something
  
})
```

I am not able see the sidebar menu also by using above code. Where have I gone wrong?

Comment: in the server, you are not doing any filtering i.e. `subset(data, col1 %in% input$input1)`

Comment: I would like to see template i.e, whether filters are created in the side bar menu or not . Using those filters I have to plot. That code did not added here.

Comment: Have you created this from a template example

Comment: I have taken that code from ``` https://github.com/rstudio/shinydashboard/issues/25```

Comment: I trieed one of the examples in that link.  It is working for me

Comment: Why am not getting. I have used same code.

Comment: Can you try my code? It is also based on that link only.

Comment: I couldn't find the specific code in that link.

Comment: I didn't get your point. you said it's working for you. Which code is working for you?

Comment: I meant that I run one of the code snippets in that link which is working for me.

Comment: I would recommend to use `FALSE` and `TRUE` instead of `F`, `T` as this can be misleading and create bugs in the future

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a `disable = T` i.e. TRUE in the code, which disable.  Change it to `FALSE`

```
shinyApp(
  ui = dashboardPage(
    dashboardHeader(title = "Dashboard",titleWidth = 2000,disable = FALSE),
    dashboardSidebar(disable = FALSE,
                     
                     sidebarMenu(
                       
                       menuItem(
                         # Input directly under menuItem
                         selectInput("input1", "Select input",
                                     choices = c(unique(data$col1))
                         )
                       ) 
                     )
    ),
    dashboardBody()
  ),
  server = function(input, output) {
    
    print("shiny")
    })
    
  }
```

Comment: Thank you for spending time on this question. It is working now.